# Find $AB=c, BC=a$ and $CA=b$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: triangles, integers

> Given a triangle $ABC$, $\angle C =90 ^{\circ}$ and $M$ is an interior point
>
> $MA, MB, MC$ are positive integers.
>
> Find $AB=c, BC=a$ and $CA=b$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$ and $MA, MB, MC$.

*I need to make an example of such a triangle and  example of such a point $M$. There are an infinite number of solutions? (Without multiplying by $k$)*

#### My work so far:

Let $C(0;0); A(0;b); B(a;0)$ and $M(x;y)$. Then 
$$MA=\sqrt{x^2+(y-b)^2} \in \mathbb Z$$
$$MB=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2} \in \mathbb Z$$
$$MC=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in \mathbb Z$$
$c^2=a^2+b^2$

[image]

#### Addition

We have:

1) triangle $ABC$, $\angle C =90 ^{\circ}$, point $M \in \triangle ABC$.

2) $MA, MB, MC$ are positive integers.

Find:

$AB, BC, CA, MA, MB, MC \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Do we allow $M$ to lie on the boundary of the triangle? If that's the case then by considering the case where $M$ is the projection of $C$ on $AB$ we can easily generate infinitely many $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy the problem.

Comment: Can we be clear on what we are given? $MA, MB, MC$, and with these three lengths, we are trying to find $a,b,c$?

Comment: @ErlangWiratamaSurya: $M$ not  to lie on the boundary of the triangle

Comment: @Shuri2060: I need to make an example of such a triangle and  example of such a point $M$

Comment: $MA,MB,MC$ being positive integers (note 'positive' is unnecessary as lengths are positive anyway) does not restrict your problem to one solution. As I've shown, there are multiple (most probably infinite) possibilities for $AB,BC,CA$.

Comment: No I don't, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $MA=r,MC=q,MB=p,\angle CMB=\alpha,\angle CMA=\beta$ , applying cosine's law,

$a^2=p^2+q^2-2pq\cosα$

$b^2=q^2+r^2-2rq\cosβ$

$c^2=p^2+r^2-2pr\cos(360-α-β)$

$\cos{\alpha},\cos{\beta}$ must be rational. Also $\sinα\sinβ$ is rational(c is integer),
let $\cos{\alpha}=\dfrac{n_1}{m_1},\cos{\beta}=\dfrac{n_2}{m_2}$

$\sqrt{\big(1-\dfrac{n_1^2}{m_1^2}\big)\big(1-\dfrac{n_2^2}{m_2^2}\big)}=\dfrac{l}{m1m2}$

$⇔(m_1^2-n_1^2)(m_2^2-n_2^2)=l^2$

$(i)$special case of $\angle AMB=\angle AMC\angle=BMC= 120°$, $(ii)$composite-number $l=(2d+1)(2e+1)$ are solutions of this equation.

$(i)$This leads possible case is $\angle AMB=\angle BMC=\angle CMA=120°$ by conditions of obtuse triangles. Thinking area of triangle,

$ab=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2(pq+pr+qr)$

This equation hold if ABC is regular triangle, or $\sin \angle ABC=\dfrac{n\sqrt3}m$.

$(ii)$ Since $m_1,n_1,m_2,n_2,d,e$ are pythagorean triples,
organizing equations of cosine's laws on coprime $(m,n)(s,t)$,
we get next parametric equation.

$2q^2+2pq(\dfrac{2mn}{m^2+n^2})+2qr(\dfrac{2st}{s^2+t^2})=2pr\dfrac{4mnst-(m^2-n^2)(s^2-t^2)}{(m^2+n^2)(s^2+t^2)}$

Answer (score 2):

If M is allowed to sit on the hypotenuse than it's easy to find an example by rescaling a [Pythagorean Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) and split it into 2 smaller Pythagorean Triangles. The full detailed explanation can be find on [this excellent page](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html#fastCalc) under section 10.1.2.

One such examples would be, using your notation:

*a* = 2625, *b* = 9000, *c* = 9375

*MA* = 8640, *MB* = 735, *MC* = 2520